# Error en manifest al abrir proyecto Android Studio en Mac, creado en Windows

Tags: android, ios, windows

estoy intentando abrir un proyecto en una mac que cree en Android Studio con el sistema operativo Windows.
Instale todo en dicha mac pero al querer abrirlo me tira un monton de errores en el manifest, he intentado modificar el gradle entre otras cosas pero nada funciona. Si alguien alguna vez migró un proyecto de windows a mac se lo agradeceria porque sinceramente no encuentro solución.

Les comparto los errores que me tira.

```html
Android resource linking failed
Output:  /Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource drawable/icono (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:drawable/icono) not found.
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource drawable/icono (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:drawable/icono) not found.
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:style/AppTheme) not found.
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:43: error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Command: /Users/macbook/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/90810c642b8f1d7913e2d0baee6cdd12/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugResources/out/resources-tummontecarloDebug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processTummontecarloDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-tummontecarloDebug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/tummontecarloDebug/processTummontecarloDebugResources/r\
        --custom-package\
        matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctest\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/build/intermediates/symbols/tummontecarlo/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

Y ESTE ES EL MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC_TRANSACTION_EVENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icono"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icono"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctest.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Ahora me tira los siguientes errores (siempre tira problemas al migrar una app desde un sistema operativo a otro ? )

```html
   Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleHernandariasDebug]

Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkHernandariasDebugClasspath
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preHernandariasDebugBuild
:app:compileHernandariasDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileHernandariasDebugRenderscript
:app:checkHernandariasDebugManifest
:app:generateHernandariasDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceHernandariasDebug
:app:generateHernandariasDebugResValues
:app:generateHernandariasDebugResources
:app:mergeHernandariasDebugResources
:app:createHernandariasDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processHernandariasDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskHernandariasDebug
:app:processHernandariasDebugResources
:app:generateHernandariasDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileHernandariasDebug
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/TwitterFragment.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_twitter, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_twitter
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/TwitterFragment.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
    final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.twitter_webview);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable twitter_webview
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/DniFragment.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
int c= R.string.NumeroE;
               ^
  symbol:   variable NumeroE
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/DniFragment.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable progressbar
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/DniFragment.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dni, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_dni
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/DniFragment.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.dni_webview);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable dni_webview
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/DniFragment.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.yaviene.com/usuario/tarjeta_input.php?c="+getString(R.string.NumeroE)+"&v=1k="+hexvalor+"&n=?");
                                                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable NumeroE
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/NfcvistaFragment.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nfc_vista, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_nfc_vista
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable activity_main
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable toolbar
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fab
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable drawer_layout
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                                           ^
  symbol:   variable navigation_drawer_open
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable navigation_drawer_close
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable nav_view
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
    final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulario_email, null);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable formulario_email
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:148: error: cannot find symbol
    final EditText etAsunto = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.et_EmailAsunto);
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable et_EmailAsunto
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:149: error: cannot find symbol
    final EditText etMensaje = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.et_EmailMensaje);
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable et_EmailMensaje
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
    final EditText etDatos = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.et_Datos);
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable et_Datos
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:151: error: cannot find symbol
    final EditText etCel = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.et_Cel);
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable et_Cel
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
    Button btnEnviarMail = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarMail);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable btnEnviarMail
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:185: error: cannot find symbol
                String[] enviar_a_correo = {getString(R.string.correo)};
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable correo
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:283: error: cannot find symbol
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,myFragment).commit();
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable content_main
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:293: error: cannot find symbol
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,myFragment).commit();
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable content_main
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:326: error: cannot find symbol
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable drawer_layout
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:358: error: cannot find symbol
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable menu
  location: class R
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:386: error: cannot find symbol
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                  ^
  symbol:   variable nav_camera
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:392: error: cannot find symbol
    else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable nav_gallery
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:396: error: cannot find symbol
    else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable nav_slideshow
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:405: error: cannot find symbol
  else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
                     ^
  symbol:   variable nav_share
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:415: error: cannot find symbol
 else if (id == R.id.nav_telefono) {
                    ^
  symbol:   variable nav_telefono
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:420: error: cannot find symbol
    else if (id == R.id.nav_salir) {
                       ^
  symbol:   variable nav_salir
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:430: error: cannot find symbol
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,miFragment).commit();
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable content_main
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/MainActivity.java:433: error: cannot find symbol
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable drawer_layout
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/YavieneFragment.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable progressbar
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/YavieneFragment.java:162: error: cannot find symbol
    final WebView webView = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.yaviene_webview);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable yaviene_webview
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/YavieneFragment.java:170: error: cannot find symbol
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.yaviene.com/usuario/index.php?a="+getString(R.string.EMPRESA)+"&v=1&lat="+latitud+"&Lng="+longitud);
                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable EMPRESA
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/YavieneFragment.java:178: error: cannot find symbol
    Log.e("ya viene","http://www.yaviene.com/usuario/index.php?a="+getString(R.string.EMPRESA)+"&v=1&lat="+latitud+"&Lng="+longitud);
                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable EMPRESA
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/YavieneFragment.java:261: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yaviene, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_yaviene
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/OmniplayFragment.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omniplay, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_omniplay
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/OmniplayFragment.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
    final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.omniplay_webview);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable omniplay_webview
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/FacebookFragment.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_facebook
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/FacebookFragment.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.facebook_webview);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable facebook_webview
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/FacebookFragment.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
    webView.loadUrl(""+getString(R.string.Facebook));
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable Facebook
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/FacebookFragment.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
    Log.e("ya viene",""+getString(R.string.Facebook));
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable Facebook
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/SplashActivity.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable activity_splash
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/SplashActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable activity_splash
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/SplashActivity.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable progressBar
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/NfcFragment.java:168: error: cannot find symbol
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable progressbar
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/NfcFragment.java:216: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nfc, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_nfc
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/NfcFragment.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
    WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.nfc_webview);
                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable nfc_webview
  location: class id
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/NfcFragment.java:222: error: cannot find symbol
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.yaviene.com/usuario/tarjeta_respuesta.php?c="+getString(R.string.NumeroE)+"&v=1&n="+serie);
                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable NumeroE
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/NfcFragment.java:224: error: cannot find symbol
    Log.e("ya viene","http://www.yaviene.com/usuario/tarjeta_respuesta.php?c="+getString(R.string.NumeroE)+"&v=1&n="+serie);
                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable NumeroE
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/TelefonoFragment.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omniplay, container, false);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable fragment_omniplay
  location: class layout
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/TelefonoFragment.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+getString(R.string.Telefono));
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable Telefono
  location: class string
/Users/macbook/Desktop/nfctest/app/src/main/java/matiasl/nfctarjeta/nfctest/WhatsappFragment.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    String uri = "whatsapp://send?phone=" + getString(R.string.NumeroWhatsapp);
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable NumeroWhatsapp
  location: class string
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
56 errors
:app:compileHernandariasDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileHernandariasDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
17 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error al parecer tienes dos problemas:

Output:

```
merged/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource drawable/icono (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:drawable/icono) not found.
merged/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource drawable/icono (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:drawable/icono) not found.
merged/AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:style/AppTheme) not found.
merged/AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
merged/AndroidManifest.xml:43: error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctesttummontecarlo:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

---

**1)** Haces referencia a un recurso llamado icono que debe encontrarse en el directorio `/drawable` y este no existe, asegura agregarlo a tu proyecto.

```
drawable/icono
```

---

**2)** Haces referencia a un tema llamado `AppTheme.NoActionBar` que no existe en tu configuración. Puedes agregarlo dentro de tu archivo `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>
```

de esta forma sera encontrado en la configuración ya que estas haciendo referencia a el en alguna Activity

Comment: Gracias amigo, la verdad las dos cosas estan. El icono lo pase de png a jpg por las dudas y al NoActionBar lo pedi de otra forma y no me marca error ahora (ya estaba en style). Ahora me tira los siguiente errores que comparto arriba en la publicacion

Comment: Veo que es un problema compilador ¿Ya revisaste la ventana del compilador que muestra?, es lo que indica el LogCat : "see the compiler error output for details.". Limpia y Genera nuevamente el proyecto probablemente con esto se muestre el problema que ahora se tiene.

Comment: Ahí modifique los errores amigo. La verdad no se ni como encararlo